# Typescript how to say two value will be same type but they could be anything

Tags: typescript, types, interface, compare

My question is for example there is a interface like this

```js
interface Example {
value: any;
otherValueToCompare: any;
}
```

They could be anything, but they should be same type.
If someone tries to send a `string` for value, otherValueToCompare's type should be `string` too.

How can it achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic types to achieve this:

```js
type Example<T> = {
    value: T;
    otherValueToCompare: T;
}

const s: Example<string> = {
    value: 'x',
    otherValueToCompare: 'y'
}

const p: Example<number> = {
    value: 1,
    otherValueToCompare: 2
}
```